# Confirming that the failure rate of a new component is less than or equal to the failure rate of the old component with 95% confidence

Tags: hypothesis-testing, confidence-interval, reliability, failure-rate

I have a new component that is meant to replace an old component that has a well-documented failure rate. Both components are buttons, and the failure rate corresponds to the mean number of button presses between failures/malfunctions, or the percent probability that a button press will not function as intended. The assumption is that a failure is temporary and subsequent button presses are still likely to succeed.

**I am trying to determine the minimum sample size (how many times I need to test the new button)  to reach a 95% confidence that the new button has a failure rate equal to or less than the old button.** If the new button experiences a failure, I want to be able to update my sample size calculation to get a new (higher) minimum sample size to reach that confidence interval. If enough failures are seen in the new switch that the required sample size becomes unrealistic to achieve, I will conclude that the new component's reliability is insufficient.

I'm thinking that a null hypothesis would work, choosing a significance value of 0.05, but I'm not sure how to set up the equation for this context.

Comment: You might be better served with a sequential test: this kind of test checks a simple criterion after each observation until a threshold is reached that tells you whether there is a significant difference or not.  It doesn't require a sample size to be be predetermined but typically requires fewer (random) samples.  The complication in this setting is that it would be reasonable to expect there to be product-to-product variation in failure rates, so that you are sampling multiple products multiple times (with each button press) and estimating an *average* rate across products.